# Actual type of generic interface method parameter

Tags: java, class, object, generics, reflection

This question has been answered when an implementing class is involved (which I don't have), but those methods are not working for me.

Let's say I have an an interface

```
public interface MySuperInterface<T> {
    public void test(T arg);
}
```

And then an extending interface

```
public interface MyInterface extends MySuperInterface<String> {

}
```

If I am iterating the methods of the MyInterface class, is it possible to get the actual type of the parameter (in this case String) of the 'test' method from the MyInterface class?

```
for (Method method : MyInterface.class.getMethods())
{
    for (Parameter parameter : method.getParameters())
    {
        final Class<?> paramClass = parameter.getType();
        System.out.println(paramClass);
    }
}
```

The above code will output 'class java.lang.Object'. Shouldn't I be able to tell that the parameter will be a String?

Comment: This seems pretty easy to just try. Why haven't you?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the implementing interface that supplies the type argument explicitly, then this is possible with reflection; the below types used are imported from `java.lang.reflect`.

First get the `Type` object corresponding to the first super-interface.

```
Type tmi = MyInterface.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
```

In this case, `tmi` is really a `ParameterizedType`, a subinterface of `Type`.  Cast it and get its type argument.

```
ParameterizedType ptmi = (ParameterizedType) tmi;
Type typeArg = ptmi.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Because you supplied a class name as a type argument instead of another parameterized type or another type parameter, `typeArg` is a `Class`, which implements `Type`.  Here, it's `java.lang.Class`.

```
System.out.println(typeArg);

class java.lang.String
```

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't nearly explicit enough in my question. I have tried to ask it again after editting it. Basically I am scanning methods for interface classes and in this instance I thought I should be able to tell that the implementation will be a String. But the methods you have shown against the parameter I cannot seem to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my utility class [`GenericUtil`](https://github.com/XDean/Java-EX/blob/297b21df13ebe25e991ec3741af21b3592e92375/src/main/java/xdean/jex/util/reflect/GenericUtil.java). It can resolve generic types.

```
Method m = MyInterface.class.getMethod("test", Object.class); // get the method
Type p = m.getGenericParameterTypes()[0]; // get the generic type 'T'
Map<TypeVariable<?>, Type> map = GenericUtil.getGenericReferenceMap(MyInterface.class); // get generic map of the class's context
System.out.println(map.get(p)); // get actual type for 'T'
```

output

```
class java.lang.String
```